# security patches are giving error

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, ce-1.9.0.0

we are using 1.9.0 version

i am trying to install the security patches through ssh

> `root@KidsDial:/var/www/html/# sh PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh`
>   PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh: 14:
>   PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh: 127: not found
>
> PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh: 14: 
>   PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh: 127: not found
>
> PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh: 25: 
>   PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh: 0: not found
>
> Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
>   Patch was applied/reverted successfully.

at the end, i am getting " Patch was applied/reverted successfully."

but above i am getting 3 lines displaying "not found", it means is patched updated succesfully..?...

when we checked here http://magento.com/security-patch, we are getting the sites is safe

Comment: What version of magento are you using?

Comment: we are using 1.9.0 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to install the patches through the command line. The best way is to follow the magento guide:

1 -Transfer the patch .sh file to your Magento installation root directory.
   For example, `/var/www/html/magento.`

2- Enter the following command as a user with sufficient privileges to write to Magento files (typically, the web server user or root):
    `sh patch-file-name.sh`

A message such as the following displays to confirm the patch installed successfully:

`Patch was applied/reverted successfully.`

source: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html

**Update**

I think you're using the wrong patch. It should be the V2 Version -  `PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2` and not the V1 version.

You may need to revert the changes that you have already done.

Comment: It would be good to write the answer in here as the link might change and then the answer would not apply anymore

Comment: @Thomas good point. Just updated.

Comment: please check the updated question. i installed through ssh .at the end, i am getting " Patch was applied/reverted successfully."

but above i am getting 3 lines displaying "not found", it means is patched updated succesfully?

Comment: @BabyinMagento2 Just updated my answer

Comment: the only security patch i found with "v1" & "v2" version is "SUPEE - 6285 "

we installed newer version "V2" only.

but we are finding those 3 line errors when installing all patches.

when we checked here http://magento.com/security-patch, we are getting the site is safe

is this enough?

Comment: but in your question above your running the following command `root@KidsDial:/var/www/html/# sh PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh ` which is for the V1 patch. On line 127 of the patch its attempting to do a dry run but is failing. Personally i'd like to see the patch install succssfully as this could lead to other issues in the future if you need to apply a new patch.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install patches by following the process as Magento recommands through SSH commands as @rob3000 suggested.

The hunk error you are getting is because patch files has coded with the specific line numbers to be changed in your current Magento files, if patch don't find the code at defined line, it will show hunk error.

The solution of that, either you can get the same file from the Magento git of same version you are using and upload it to your server and then patch. Or you can follow this blog for the patch installation without ftp. http://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-security-patches/

Comment: please check the updated question. i installed through ssh .at the end, i am getting " Patch was applied/reverted successfully."

but above i am getting 3 lines displaying "not found", it means is patched updated succesfully?